# Setting up nested dictionaries in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, associative-array

I'm finding the CoffeeScript compiler baulks at this :

```
a = {'a':1,
     'b': { 'b1':1, 'b2':2 }
     }
```

Is that right? CoffeeScript can't create nested dictionaries?

Comment: `a = {'a':1, 'b': { 'b1':1, 'b2':2 } }` (as displayed in the rss feed) works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested JavaScript objects or "dicts" is no match for the CS compiler.

```
a =
   a: 1
   b:
     b1: 1
     b2: 2
```

Produces this

```
a = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    b1: 1,
    b2: 2
  }
};
```

Comment: OK. That's what I did. But it's a bit of a pain in this case. I have a bunch of 4-item, secondary level dictionaries (each of which basically a compass with "N", "E", "S", "W" as keys). 

It fits nicely in the page with that second level on a single line, but takes up a lot more space in this format.

Answer (score 1):

CoffeeScript is whitespace sensitive, even when using braces. Either don't use the braces as suggested by limelights, or ensure that the whitespace matches when using braces:

```
a = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': { 'b1': 1, 'b2': 2 }
}
```